# How do developers create animated transitions between sections?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I am currently coding a landing page in React, and I was wondering how do developers code transitions in between their website's section. To be more specific, I am required to have these transitions similar to [Canvas United's website](https://www.canvasunited.com/). I also have experience with Adobe After Effects if that could be a possible solution.

[Beginning of Canvas United's section transition!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzcco.jpg)
[Middle of Canvas United's section transition!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9YAL.png)

The way that a green block slides in and slides out, indicating a new section is percisely what I need. If someone could lead me in the correct direction, it would be of great help!

Answer (score 1):

As you are a beginner of coding it seems to you it is hard. but it is quite easy. just of `css`, `html` and`js` . here is an   [example](https://codepen.io/ste-vg/pen/NALWrj) for you. I think it best suits your question. You can refer all those codes for your development.

Comment: You are amazing! This is actually really helpful. Thanks again!